# ASP.NET MVC4 client side validation does not recognize decimals

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

my problem is that the client side validation for floats gives not a number when I type a number with not exactly 3 numbers after the decimal point.
Ex: 5,4 or 5,4444 gives must be a number, but 5,444 is correct.

When I disable client side, the server side validation lets it pass, ...

Comment: Can you paste code here?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is a culture issue as explained [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b65290d2-2483-44dd-abce-bbf7158eaeeb/default-validation-of-float-fields-fails-with-the-field-fieldname-must-be-a-number?forum=adodotnetentityframework).

I suspect so because you seem to have a Dutch/Belgian name where we use `,` for decimals whereas in the US `,` is used for digit grouping in large numbers (hence the 3 digits, 5,444 would be five thousand four hundred and forty four).

If that turns out to be the issue, this Github Project: [jquery-validation-globalize](https://github.com/johnnyreilly/jquery-validation-globalize) is a great resource.

You can perhaps verify this first before looking at other causes.